# Responsive Image Gallery Div Height Issue - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build up a responsive image gallery by following w3schools tutorials. Everything seems to working very fine except one serious issue. I googled a lot but couldn't find any silver bullet solution to fix it. I'm posting a screenshot to make your better understand about my issue. Here's a look:

[image]

It's very much obvious what's the real problem. Right. So what should we do? Should we have to give a min-height for every div? The text comes dynamically from the database and sometimes it is mandatory to display complete text without trimming it.

**Note:**

Using min-height causes one another problem. When we resize the browser to tab width then it creates a lot of blank space between div rows.

Comment: It's not wise to use plugin even for such simple tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You've not post a code, so I can offer you a [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) solution. 
Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8paq6e34/21/).

These flexible boxes will stretch according to the text and they will fit the parent container, regardless of the text inside. I hope it will help you. Flexbox is a layout system which is very powerful and easy to learn, and it is mobile ready.

```
 .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.img {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case that (almost) full and guaranteed support for the latest IE versions is required (or you want a fallback of some sort), and you do not wish to use JavaScript, there's also the option of using `text-align: center` on container and on image wrappers `display: inline-block` as well as `vertical-align: top`.

The `text-align: center` isn't actually required, but it will center the image wrappers (containers of image and image text).

This will still leave some white space beneath the image wrappers but each image will start on the same line, so to speak.

You can see a fiddle here, based on the layout of @Julsy : [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbubvv38/2/)

Note:
This solution does have a slight downside regarding white space due to the `inline-block` elements. This means that sometimes setting two `inline-block` elements to 50% width each will make them jump to each separate line. However I've used this solution in several applications by simply setting the width to 49% e.g. In many cases the difference isn't noticable at all, and given the white space between the elements they often are aligned properly (in my opinion). The white space can even make up for some of the spacing between the elements such as margin.

The white space stems from the actual spaces in the text of your HTML document.

You can read a bit about the phenomenon of these white spaces [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). It seems that it's not really an error, but just the way the browser works.

The prettiest solution in my opinion surely is the one @Julsy suggests (the flexbox method).

As to why your own code isn't working is due to the `float`. When one of the elements is lower (lower `height`) than the other, the element following it will "float" underneath it. I think that the logic behind this can be thought of as the following (correct me if i'm wrong): if you view the containing element is a set of "text lines" (as in a regular book or text in here) with a reading direction from left to right, the element with `float:left` will attempt to get as close to the upper-left corner as possible (which is where you start reading from). In this case, the closest place to the upper-left corner is beneath the lower element as this is on a "line" above the bottom of the highest element.

I hope it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you already wrote, a `min-height` is the best method to make those floated boxes be the same height and still have the "emergeny option"  to expand them if there is more content.

Comment: I just made editing in my question to tell people on STO that it causes one another issue.

Comment: then you'll need a media query which takes care of that situation

Answer (score 0):

Add display: flex to the parent element. For more info about [flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

i tried to do the same with only css, but i got tired, maybe u can use javascript to fit these kind of stuff with different heights, because these needs to be calculated, i use this: http://masonry.desandro.com/ basically this convert every element with position absolute and give it top and left positions from prevs/next elements, for example

- the first (size 100x200) will got left 0 and top 0,
- the second (size 100x400) will got left 100 and top 0,
- the third (size 100x200) will got left 0 and top 200,
- the four (size 100x200) will got left 100 and top 400)

and continues...